# How to launch an app in ios5 Simulator when we have the app in other os versions like ios5.1, ios6?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5

I have 3 OSs' in my simulator iOS5.0, iOS5.1, and iOS6.0. Is there a way to launch an application in a certain iOS version?

open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app .

This does not help much and always launches in iOS6.

*Update: I am looking for a way to do this programatically.*

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Xcode-->Preferences-->Downloads and you'll get a screen like this:

[image]

From there you can download other simulators and then you'll be able to choose them

Comment: I need a way to do this using a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Just open the Simulator, change the iOS version and afterwards press run in XCode. (You're deployment target must be right though)

Comment: I need a way to do this using a shell script.